# Journey Builder Decision Step Not allowing contacts that should go through

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

[image]

The problem is that the decision split logic is removing everyone that enters the journey which is incorrect as there are many contacts that should flow through that meet the exclusion parameters listed above. Basically everyone that enters is excluded even though there are contacts who match the criteria and should be allowed through.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that the decision split logic is removing everyone that enters the journey which is incorrect as there are many contacts that should flow through that meet the exclusion parameters listed above. 

Basically everyone that enters is excluded even though there are contacts who match the criteria and should be allowed through.